# is there a function (macro) in microsoft word to auto past whatever in the clipboard?

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy

is there a function (macro) in microsoft word to auto past whatever in the clipboard ?
i m working on macro to check if there is a new content in the clipboard and past it in the word without my participation in the process

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i m trying to copy a paragraph from program and past it in word document, and this program only allows 4 sentence to copy so i m trying to cut the process by auto past whatever in clipboard in word document without going there

Comment: You would need some kind of hook into the Windows clipboard in order to have the clipboard tell you about something happening in it. There's probably some low-level Win32 API functions that can do this, but I wouldn't recommend going down that path if you don't know what you're doing. Any other approach cannot tell you whether the clipboard content is "new" - or if it's even usable in Word. You say you mean to paste paragraphs. What if a website URL or some picture ends up in the clipboard? Clipboard is OS-wide, not just inside Word.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of that program? Does that program have an API you can use? Can you find the window containing the data you need to copy in Spy++? If so, then you can probably use Win32 API to integrate with this program in a much more robust way than through the clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, please:

1. Insert a form in your document project or Normal.dot. This must be done only to receive a reference ('Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library'). Now you can delete it. The reference will remain. Theoretically, you can directly add the reference, but sometimes Word does not show it between the one possible to be added;
2. Insert a standard module and paste the next code:

```
Sub testPutfromclipboard()
  Dim clp As DataObject, nextLine As String
  
  'nextLine = vbCrLf
  Set clp = New DataObject
   clp.GetFromClipboard
   If clp.GetFormat(1) Then
        If clp.GetText <> Empty Then
            ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=nextLine & clp.GetText
            clp.SetText Text:=Empty: clp.PutInClipboard
        End If
   End If
End Sub
```

3. Run it and a the clipboard will be Pasted on the end of the active document text.

If you want it to be Pasted on the next line, just un-comment the line `'nextLine = vbCrLf`...

Comment: This gets clipboard content.... OP is looking for a way to *know when new content is written to the clipboard* - this isn't going to cut it.

Comment: user defined type not defined, if i can only past what is in the clipboard

Comment: @Yahya-_ it's "paste", not "past", and the `DataObject` type is defined in the MSForms type library, which this answer explains how to correctly reference: you skipped step 1.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon : I did not understand the question exactly in these terms... But English is not my best point... I updated the answer  to check the clipboard content and make it `""` after taking its content. The above sequence can be called by an API timer, I think, if he needs to automatically take text form clipboard if the previous one has been changed...

Comment: @Yahya -_: Did you add the reference to 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library', as explained in the first step?

Comment: Yeah it needs some polling mechanism, and then it's all downhill from here :) IMO solving the *actual* OP's problem (read content from another running application) without involving the clipboard would be a much better solution, but the OP isn't giving us anything to chew on, so...

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon :  I can accept that. It would not be so complicated to extract text  from a window using API. Basically, `FindWindow, FindWindowEx, GetWindowText, GetWindnowTextLength, GetWindow` and `SendMessage` will do it if we will have acces to the application interface (using Spy++)....

Comment: it worked just wanted to past it in the doc without msgbox

Comment: @Yahya -_: Adapted the code to Paste after the existing text... Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can poll say once a second.

```
Public Declare Function GetClipboardOwner Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function GetClipboardSequenceNumber Lib "user32" () As Long

RTFString = RTFString & "\b1 Clipboard Sequence Number: \b0 " & CStr(GetClipboardSequenceNumber()) & "\par" & vbCr
RTFString = RTFString & "\b1 Clipboard Owner Window Handle: \b0 " & CStr(GetClipboardOwner()) & "\par" & vbCr
Msgbox RTFString
```

There is also a better way but it requires you to sub class a form. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener

You don't need to sub class a form, you could sub class Excel's main window.